# Can a subject in Bell-LaPadula model write to other files with different compartments but same classification?

Tags: access-control, mandatory-access-control, bell-lapadula

my question is based on the post made Toaster which never got a reply ([Bell-LaPadula Model Compartments](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/255077/bell-lapadula-model-compartments)). In BLP If a subject has a classification level General and compartment Land (General, {Land}), would he be able to read/write to (General, {Sea}) which has the same classification but different compartment?

Also if he wants to read a file of lower classification AND different compartment, e.g. (Soldier, {Air}, would he be unable to do so becasue he does not have the same compartment?

Comment: @D.W. I've read your comment at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8683/bell-lapadula-imlementation-example, which is amazingly well explained. Would you mind please to answer me this question given you are an BLP expert?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - No and No

I'm assuming in your classification system that a "General" has a higher sensitivity level (e.g. Top Secret) than a "Soldier" (e.g. Secret).

> (General, {Land}), would he be able to read/write to (General, {Sea})

No, for both read and write because Land and Sea are separate compartments.

> Classification labels are of the form (Sr, Sc) where Sr is a sensitivity and Sc is a set of compartments. We say that (Or, Oc) dominates (Sr, Sc) if (Sr, Sc) <= (Or, Oc). This <= relation is true when
> Sr <= Or where the <= relationship here is with respect to the classified/sensitive/secret/top secret sensitivity classification, **and**
> Sc <= Oc where the <= relationship is a subset relation on sets.

> read a file of lower classification AND different compartment

No again, based on the discretionary control of the compartment.  If the object was (Soldier, {Land}) access would be granted but because it's a different compartment, no.

> Even if someone has all the necessary official approvals (such as a security clearance) to access certain information they should not be given access to such information unless they have a need to know: that is, unless access to
> the specific information necessary for the conduct of one's official duties.

**References**
[Multi-level Security](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs513/2000SP/L11.html)
[Purdue CS426 Fall 2010 Lecture 21](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/ninghui/courses/426_Fall10/handouts/426_Fall10_lect21.pdf)